# How do I get the spinner clicked item out of the onItemSelectedListener in this fragment?

Tags: android, listener, spinner, android-arrayadapter, onitemselectedlistener

I have the following code. I want the onItemSelectedListener to put the value of the selected string into store_id for further processing. I've used Toast to examine it because I can't put a watch on the listener and store_id is default null.  The spinner shows my various strings but disappears when clicked upon. Any ideas? I can't imagine my problem is having all the code in this fragment together...[output right before clicking on a store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yK1Ol.png)

```
public class ChooseStoreFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
ArrayList<String> store_array = new ArrayList<>();
String store_id;

//implementing the AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String user_store_id = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();//doesn't show up in toast
    store_id = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();//doesn't show up in toast
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), user_store_id + "=user_store_id.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),"Nothing selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View thisView = inflater.inflate(fragment_choose_store, container, false);
    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) thisView.findViewById(R.id.stores_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,store_array);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener mListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            store_id = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
        } //still never shows up in toast

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "none found = user_store_id.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //still nothing
        }
    };
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(mListener);
```

Comment: You have implemented two `AdapterView.OnitemSelectedListener`. Which one do you want?

Comment: The first one.  The second implementation was just an attempt at more locality being an issue!?

Answer (score 0):

You have already registered a listener for the `spinner`, so you don't have to make `ChooseStoreFragment` implement that `listener` again.

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(mListener);
```

It should be like this

```
public class ChooseStoreFragment extends Fragment {
    ArrayList<String> store_array = new ArrayList<>();
    String store_id;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View thisView = inflater.inflate(fragment_choose_store, container, false);
        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) thisView.findViewById(R.id.stores_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, store_array);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener mListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                store_id = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
            } //still never shows up in toast

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "none found = user_store_id.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //still nothing
            }
        };
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(mListener); // Register this spinner for a mListener
    }
}
```

Or if you want to register listener for you class

```
public class ChooseStoreFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    ArrayList<String> store_array = new ArrayList<>();
    String store_id;

    //implementing the AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String user_store_id = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();//doesn't show up in toast
        store_id = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();//doesn't show up in toast
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), user_store_id + "=user_store_id.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Nothing selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View thisView = inflater.inflate(fragment_choose_store, container, false);
        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) thisView.findViewById(R.id.stores_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, store_array);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);// register this fragment with a listener
    }
}
```

Register for only 1 listener!

UPDATED:

```
public class ChooseStoreFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    ArrayList<String> store_array = new ArrayList<>();
    String store_id;

    //implementing the AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String user_store_id = store_array.get(position);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), user_store_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Nothing selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View thisView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_choose_store, container, false);
        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) thisView.findViewById(R.id.stores_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, store_array);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);// register this fragment with a listener
        return thisView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your code, thank you, nice and cleaner, but there is still no data going from onItemSelected to store_id.   Can you look at the parent.getSelectedItem() line/method?

Comment: because your store_array doesn't contain anything

Comment: But it does, it gets loaded by a VolleyRequest and the spinner shows the data.  The screenshot from my output wasn't allowed in my question yet(low rank).  Would you take a look at the screenshot?

Comment: I updated for last time, please consider to rewrite your code.

Comment: I think I will post the successful code I've come up with, #include thanks to Phat, it's ugly because I've had to add a system clock delay, but it's superficial to the app. If anything, I'd say the language isn't ready to implement user-defined spinners from fragments considering this example. Cheers!